# Is there a way to find a certain occurrence of a node within a certain parent node

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have searched many places online for an answer and perhaps i'm over reading some or not researching into it hard enough aswell as being fairly new to XML reading and all but is there a way to let's say use `getelementbytagname()` but have it only search within a certain occurance of a parent node so ideal would be `getelementbytagname("childnode").("parentnode").(i)` where i is incrementing at a certain point. parentnode is of the same name so in my case theres multiple "Header" tag within the file with info i need within of same names.

I know how to go and read a xml file and i also know how to extract info I realistically want but I'm at a point where it is getting very messy and just proving way too tedious. An example would be say I have an XML file and there are 3 different records basically within, "Header" being the parent and then it would have child nodes/elements such as "billnumber","customername" etc. and these would be called the same in each "Header" just different values.

While xml.Read

```
            If xml.Name = "Header" Then


                builder.Append("Bill:")

                xml.Read()



                While Not xml.Name = "Header"


                    xml.WhitespaceHandling = 1


                    If xml.Name = "BillNumber" Then
                        xml.Read()

                        BillNumber = xml.value()

                         xml.Read()

                    End If
```

So that is a brief way of how im going about getting info from certain "headers" and I was wondering is there a way i could get the count of "Header" elements by using `count = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Header").Count` then basically using a counter such as `i` to then like i said do somthing like `getElementByTagName("BillNumber").("Header").(i)` or similar. This way i can avoid reading the whole file and just handpick certian parts as there is tons more info within the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your XML looks something like this...

```
<header>
  <billnumber>1</billnumber>
  <customername>john</customername>
</header>
<header>
  <billnumber>2</billnumber>
  <customername>bob</customername>
</header>
<header>
  <billnumber>3</billnumber>
  <customername>richard</customername>
</header>
```

You can use the methods in the System.XML namespace to work with this very easily.  If my understanding of your question is correct, this should be a good starting point:

```
Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load("myfile.xml")

For Each HeaderNode As System.Xml.XmlNode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("header")
    Debug.Print("bill number is: " & HeaderNode("billnumber").Value)
    Debug.Print("customer name is: " & HeaderNode("customer name").Value)
Next
```